# Opacity from 0 to 1 animation not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, animation, opacity

As the title says, this animation is not working on Firefox.

I am running this animation through **JavaScript** after a few seconds by using:

```
document.getElementById('my_id').style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
```

I also tried:

```
style.animationPlayState
```

In the same file, changing the background-color animation works perfectly.
My conclusion is, there is something wrong with opacity on Firefox?

```
#my_id {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animation 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation: animation 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation: animation 1s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes animation {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0.2;}
}
```

The above CSS is from the element I want to animate.

Comment: You have no closing brace (`}`), your `-webkit-animation` property has `1ss` instead of `1s`. Also, you should be toggling a CSS class to elicit a CSS animation, instead of setting the CSS property itself with JS.

Comment: You know you're missing an ending `}` I presume?

Comment: yup I failed in copying my code.. That's not the problem.

Comment: Which version of firefox are you running?

Comment: 51.0.1 (32-bit)

Comment: odd, because since 49 the default is to "recognise" some webkit prefixed css attributes ... try setting the `mozAnimationPlayState` and `animationPlayState` to running as well - because your code works fine as is for me in Firefox 51+  - check that `layout.css.prefixes.webkit` is true in `about:config` - [your code working](https://jsfiddle.net/q76z77zq/)

Comment: and note that your code is almost guaranteed to fail on firefox < 49 due to the comment above :p

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **JavaScript** to add `-webkit-animation-play-state`, just add a class to your `#my_id` `div` using `onload` that includes all of the browser prefixes.

### JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("my_id").className += "running";
}
```

### CSS

```
#my_id.running {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

The above code adds the `.running` class to your `#my_id` element, which declares `animation-play-state: running`, including the browser prefixes. You can test the above code by checking out my [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpjGwP) that uses your code. I've tested it and it works in Firefox (**51**), Chrome, Opera, & Safari.

Comment: Obviously I'm just using `onload` for the example. You can change the statement to wait a few seconds before running the `function`.

Comment: Well, that finally started to work. This and previous solution are fine now.
But there's another problem. Not working when i'm trying to put SVG image.
 `<svg  id="svg_id" viewBox=" 5 -200 1000 1000">
<image id="my_id" xlink:href="L_1_1.png"/></svg>
` this one works with first solution only on Chrome, and with your solution not working at all. Is there a problem with my svg include?